# Combining Tables Based On Condition

Tags: r

Can I find out if there is any code that creates a table or data frame that binds multiple tables for me?

```
table(df$col1)
table(df$col1,df$col2<0)
table(df$col1,df$col3>0)
table(df$col1,df$col4>0)
```

In the above example, I am grouping my dataset based on similar values in `df$col1` and displaying data that satisfy the condition `df$col2<0`. What I get is a true and false matrix of the number of records fulfilling the condition and not. I want a combined table that still groups the data by `df$col1` and shows the true condition for `df$col2<0,df$col3>0` and `df$col4>0` in the same table.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already done so, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask good answerable questions. Can you edit your question to show the result you're getting and how you want it to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description, we could do a `cbind`

```
r1 <- cbind(table(df$col1), table(df$col1,df$col2<0)[,2],
     table(df$col1,df$col3>0)[,2], table(df$col1,df$col4>0)[,2])
```

---

If there are many columns, this can be done by looping

```
r2 <- do.call(cbind, c(list(col1 = table(df$col1)), Map(function(x, y)  
     table(df$col1, get(y)(x, 0))[,2], df[-1], c("<", ">", ">"))))

all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

We can also do this with group by operations.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(col2 = col2 < 0) %>%
    mutate_at(3:4, funs(. > 0)) %>% 
    group_by(col1) %>% 
    mutate(n = n()) %>%
    group_by(n, add = TRUE) %>% 
    summarise_all(sum)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-2:5, 10*4, replace = TRUE), ncol=4))
names(df) <- paste0("col", 1:4)
```

Comment: Yes this worked for me but is there a way to rename the columns including table(df$col1). i tried using colnames but could not rename the first column.

Comment: @xyn If you look at `r2`, the column names are 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'.  For `r1`, it can be `colnames(r1) <- paste0("col", 1:4)`